# Primefaces p:panelGrid cosider a comment as an component

Tags: primefaces

I'm using the component p: panelGrid, and within it put various components of my form. I was surprised when, in order to facilitate understanding of the code, I put a comment, and he regarded it as a component and ordered form based on the comment.

Can anyone explain to me why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS` to true in `web.xml`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: By ur answer i can think its normal p:panelGrid consider a comment as an component?

Comment: @ColdHack Not just `<p:panelGrid/>`, `Facelets` in general - yes.

Comment: @ColdHack Or you could use `<ui:remove><!-- remove this comment --></ui:remove>` to remove a specific comment only.

Comment: I think it's not right `Facelets` consider a comment as an component, but ok. ^^

Comment: @ColdHack Yes, at first consideration you'd expect that not being right. However, what if you want comments in the generated HTML? In order to support that, comments are parsed and then rendered as well.